# Application not able to restrict DocuSign envelopes from sending to Third Party(Customers) using API who don't have DocuSign account created

Tags: api, docusignapi

While sending documents to Third Party(Customers) through API. DocuSIgn API doesn't restrict our application to send documents to customers, when customers don't have their DocuSign account created. Ideally our application should not be able to send documents to Third Party(Customers). Our application should get an error message" Not a Valid User". Is there any way, we can restrict our application to send envelope to third part until they create their DocuSIgn account first usign API.

Comment: Is the sending account set up for part 11 compliance? The part 11 compliance setting makes the change you want happen.

Answer (score 0):

Pratyush...I will reach back to you privately, to provide access to a Part 11 enabled sandbox account for your testing.

DocuSign recipients by default do not require accounts.  You may optionally require that, along with a required login.  With Part 11 compliant accounts, the platform determines if an account must be provisioned and does that automatically.  No need for any coding...just an account setting.

Part 11 means more than just requiring a login to sign, but re-authenticating each time a signature is required, and displaying specific information visually within the signature itself.  DocuSign fully meets all Part 11 requirements, which could be more than you are requesting.

DocuSign intentionally limits discovery of existing accounts via the API, as that could impose security consequences.